# How to overload a parent's method in a child class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to write a javascript class which extends from a parent class, overloads one method  and changes it slightly.

E.g it checks some variables, if they are set to true, then it executes the same method on parent, otherwise it executes some different code.

This is what I've come up with:

```
function Dad(name)    
{
    this.yell = function()
    {
        console.log( 'GRRRRRRR ' + name);
    }
}

function Kid(name, age)    
{
    var parent = new Dad(name);


    parent.yell = function()
    {
        if (age < 15)
            console.log( 'BAAAAA ' + name );
        else
            parent.yell(); //This is the problem line, how to call this method on
                           //parent object
    }
    return parent;
}

var k = new Kid('bob', 13);
k.yell();
```

However the issue is, how to call the method on the parent object.

Any ideas?

Comment: the usual approach is to store the `yell` method in `Dad.prototype`, where it can later be safely found.

Comment: When you do `parent.yell = ...`, the original function stored at that location is lost, so you'd need to store it in advance somewhere to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use prototypes. They allow you to access the methods of the superclass, but without instantiating it.

Then, from the child class, you can do `SuperClass.prototype.instanceMethod.call(this)`, which is basically `super` in most typical OO languages, but JS doesn't help you figure out what the superclass is. So you have to keep track of it yourself.

```
// Superclass
function Dad() {};
Dad.prototype.yell = function() {
    console.log("Do your homework!");
}

// Subclass
function Kid(age) {
    // calls the constructor of the superclass.
    // in this case, the Dad() constructor does nothing, so it's not required here.
    Dad.call(this);

    // save constructor argument into this instance.
    this.age = age;
};

// Inheritance happens here, prototype is an instance of superclass
Kid.prototype = new Dad();

// Make sure the constructor is properly assigned.
Kid.prototype.constructor = Kid;

// Override an instance method.
Kid.prototype.yell = function() {
    if (this.age < 18) {
        console.log('Waaaaa, I hate homework');
    } else {
        // calls the yell method of the superclass
        Dad.prototype.yell.call(this);
    }
}

// make a kid.
var k = new Kid(13);
k.yell(); // 'Waaaaa, I hate homework' 

// make an old kid.
var k = new Kid(30);
k.yell(); // 'Do your homework!'
```

OO inheritance in JS can be messy, but there is some things out there to help.

- [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
- [Resig's Simple javaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)
- [Coffeescript classes](http://coffeescript.org/#classes)

To name a few.

Comment: I vote to add an extra line `Kid.prototype.constructor = Kid` to help Firefox correctly name the object.

Comment: That sorta sucks since I'll have to change all the methods of the Superclass to use prototype instead of the this.function syntax. Is that going to break any existing code which uses the superclass?

Comment: Also, there are a lot of private variables defined in the parent function, i.e `function Dad() { var privVar, privVar2}` etc. Are all those going to be lost if I switch to the prototype syntax?

Comment: It's hard to maintain privately scoped variables with prototypes.  But it's much harder to not use prototypes when you are doing inheritance. Typically, "private" variables are stored as properties of `this` with an underscore prefix `this._age = age`. It's not truly private, but that only matter if security is a real concern.

Comment: I can't use this method in this case without breaking a lot of backwards compatibility then, but in future I'll just do away with private vars and use `this.var` instead.